# How do I access the list of stop words in RTextTools?

Tags: r, stop-words

While there have been answers about providing custom lists of stop words to RTextTools, I would like to know about any command to access the existing/default stop word list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the given `language`, it's e.g. `tm::stopwords("german")` or `tm::stopwords("english")`:

```
head(tm::stopwords("french"))
# [1] "au"   "aux"  "avec" "ce"   "ces"  "dans"
```

Comment: stopwords(kind = "en") brought more stopwords into the limelight. The command you have suggested doesn't show all stopwords apparently.

Comment: @HimabinduBoddupalli `all(tm::stopwords("english")==tm::stopwords(kind="en"))` => `TRUE` => it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
stopwords(kind = "en") also helps.
```